# Import ipfs in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ipfs, js-ipfs, ipfs-http-client

Importing and module initialization is generally simple using JavaScript/TypeScript using either `require` or `import`. I'm having trouble running the basic example from the JS IPFS [website](https://js.ipfs.io/#:%7E:text=js-ipfs%20also%20comes%20with%20the%20option%20to%20run,distribute%20updates%20in%20an%20authenticated%20and%20certified%20way.) to initialize `ipfs`.

If I follow the general instructions I get an error: `Module parse failed: Cannot use keyword 'await' outside an async function (6:13)`

This is the critical code:

```
const IPFS = require('ipfs-core');
const ipfs = await IPFS.create();
```

If I follow the suggestion to place the `ipfs` creation in an `async` function I just delay the inevitable. If I call such a function twice I get an error from `Unhandled Rejection (LockExistsError): Lock already being held for file: ipfs/repo.lock`.  It seems I could create a hack to test whether `ipfs` is created or not and initialize it global to a module as null, but that would still be a hack.

How should I implement or refactor `const ipfs = await IPFS.create();` without error?

Answer (score 2):

Probably your Node version is prior to version 14 and don't support calling await in the top-level. You got be in the context of an async block. You can do something like:

```js
const IPFS = require('ipfs')

async function main() {
  const ipfs = await IPFS.create()
  /* Your code here */
}

// and now you can tell node to run your async main function...
main()
```

Check https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await for more info about it in the v8 engine. And also found this post about the Node 14 support for it: https://pprathameshmore.medium.com/top-level-await-support-in-node-js-v14-3-0-8af4f4a4d478

Comment: That's useful documentation, but I cannot put the code in an async function like that in a straightforward way because of the second error I mentioned: If I call such a function twice I get an error from Unhandled Rejection (LockExistsError): Lock already being held for file: ipfs/repo.lock.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was due to me initializing IFPS unnecessarily too many times in a row. After making sure the IPFS instance is only initialized once when my app starts, I was able to resolve the error.

```
let ready = false
if(!ready) {
  const ipfs = await IPFS.create()
  ready = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the user input goes to ipfs and on additional upload the error "ipfs/repo.lock" continued to come up.

After some research on ipfs wiki, it appears that there are conflicts with how ipfs actually works. Randomization of repo name is a very rough patch in this case:

`const node = await IPFS.create({ repo: "ok" + Math.random() });`